# How can I filter through an array of objects to select a value that does not have a slack in the output

Tags: typescript

I am trying to loop through an array of objects and want to select anything that has `name: item` but not `name: item/anotheritem`.

Example:

```
const orgUnitArray = [(organizationConfig.organizationalUnits)]

console.log(orgUnitArray)

console.log
  [
    [
      { name: 'Security', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Infrastructure', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Sandbox', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Workloads', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Workloads/Workload1', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Workloads/Workload2', ignore: undefined }
    ]
  ]
```

Expected:

```
console.log
  [
    [
      { name: 'Security', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Infrastructure', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Sandbox', ignore: undefined },
      { name: 'Workloads', ignore: undefined },
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: `orgUnitArray.filter(item => !item.name.includes("/"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check whether a item's name includes a `"/"` and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by that criteria.

```js
const orgUnitArray = [
  {name: "Security", ignore: undefined},
  {name: "Infrastructure", ignore: undefined},
  {name: "Sandbox", ignore: undefined},
  {name: "Workloads", ignore: undefined},
  {name: "Workloads/Workload1", ignore: undefined},
  {name: "Workloads/Workload2", ignore: undefined}
];

console.log(orgUnitArray.filter(item => !item.name.includes("/")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this helped and gave me something to work with

```
const orgUnitArray = (organizationConfig.organizationalUnits).filter(function (orgUnit) {
  return orgUnit.name.indexOf('/') === -1;
})
```

output:

```
 console.log
 [
  { name: 'Security', ignore: undefined },
  { name: 'Infrastructure', ignore: undefined },
  { name: 'Sandbox', ignore: undefined },
  { name: 'Workloads', ignore: undefined }
  ]
```